# Access is writing numbers next to each other instead of adding them up

Tags: ms-access, textbox, sum, textfield, listfield

I want to add up some list fields that are filled with numbers from a table if I press a button. For debugging I have chosen easy values.

The first field below should contain the mean value of all fields, the second one should contain the sum, and the third one should contain the sum of each column multiplied by a certain percentage and then summed (formula & pictures below).

By default, if no percentage values are given, it should only show the sum.

Here is the Problem:

Everything works fine and as intended, with or without percentage given:

[image: works fine and as intended]

Except when I enter values or a value into row number 2:

[image: enter values or a value into row number 2].

Then, the field that normally shows the sum (correct for every other row) just puts every number of every row next to each other instead of summing them. This also happens if a percentage is given.

If I empty row 2, it works correctly again.

I cannot explain why this happens, does anyone have an idea why?

The formula for the last field is:

(`CB` is Column 1, `OF` is Column 2 and `AS` is Column 3, and `[FehlleistungXX]` is the Field with the percent value:)

```
=0+Nz([DeltaDetailCB1]+[DeltaDetailCB2]+[DeltaDetailCB3]+[DeltaDetailCB4]+[DeltaDetailCB5]+[DeltaDetailCB6]+[DeltaDetailCB7]+[DeltaDetailCB8]+[DeltaDetailCB9]+[DeltaDetailCB10]+[DeltaDetailCB11]+[DeltaDetailCB12]+[DeltaDetailCB13]+[DeltaDetailCB14]+[DeltaDetailCB15]+[DeltaDetailCB16];0)*Nz(1+[FehlleistungCB]*0,01;0)

+Nz([DeltaDetailAS1]+[DeltaDetailAS2]+[DeltaDetailAS3]+[DeltaDetailAS4]+[DeltaDetailAS5]+[DeltaDetailAS6]+[DeltaDetailAS7]+[DeltaDetailAS8]+[DeltaDetailAS9]+[DeltaDetailAS10]+[DeltaDetailAS11]+[DeltaDetailAS12]+[DeltaDetailAS13]+[DeltaDetailAS14]+[DeltaDetailAS15]+[DeltaDetailAS16];0)*Nz(1+[FehlleistungAS]*0,01;0)

+Nz([DeltaDetailOF1]+[DeltaDetailOF2]+[DeltaDetailOF3]+[DeltaDetailOF4]+[DeltaDetailOF5]+[DeltaDetailOF6]+[DeltaDetailOF7]+[DeltaDetailOF8]+[DeltaDetailOF9]+[DeltaDetailOF10]+[DeltaDetailOF11]+[DeltaDetailOF12]+[DeltaDetailOF13]+[DeltaDetailOF14]+[DeltaDetailOF15]+[DeltaDetailOF16];0)*Nz(1+[FehlleistungOF]*0,01;0)
```

**Edit 1:** I tried deleting the Fields and replacing them with copies from the other fields, that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest enclosing each of the fields within an `Nz` expression, rather than selectively enclosing calculated expressions within `Nz` expressions, i.e.:

```
=
(
    (
        Nz([DeltaDetailCB1],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailCB2],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailCB3],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailCB4],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailCB5],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailCB6],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailCB7],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailCB8],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailCB9],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailCB10],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailCB11],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailCB12],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailCB13],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailCB14],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailCB15],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailCB16],0)
    ) *
    (1+(Nz([FehlleistungCB],0)*0.01))
)
+
(
    (
        Nz([DeltaDetailAS1],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailAS2],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailAS3],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailAS4],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailAS5],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailAS6],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailAS7],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailAS8],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailAS9],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailAS10],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailAS11],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailAS12],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailAS13],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailAS14],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailAS15],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailAS16],0)
    ) *
    (1+(Nz([FehlleistungAS],0)*0.01))
)
+
(
    (
        Nz([DeltaDetailOF1],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailOF2],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailOF3],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailOF4],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailOF5],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailOF6],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailOF7],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailOF8],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailOF9],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailOF10],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailOF11],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailOF12],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailOF13],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailOF14],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailOF15],0)+
        Nz([DeltaDetailOF16],0)
    ) *
    (1+(Nz([FehlleistungOF],0)*0.01))
)
```

My suspicion would be that the value returned by the `Nz` function was being interpreted as a string with the addition operator(`+`) then used to concatenate the string returned by each `Nz` expression.

If my code yields the same result, you can force the data type coercion by enclosing the entire expression within `CDbl()`.

However, I must say that repeating this many fields in a single expression is a red flag that you have a poorly designed database.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it! The Form from wich you see the fields on the pictures has slots to show up to 16 Objects from a Database at once. Each object has 3 different hour values. These hours are loaded into the list fields and the code you are seeing is for adding up the values. It's a complex method but I need to be able to compare and add up this many objects. Thats why the form may look a bit bloated. Any advice for doing better?

Edit: I tried, but it still is bugged as soon as values are filled into the fields of the second row

Comment: **It works now**, enforcing a Double explicitly on row number 2 solved the problem for me. I still dont get how 3 fields out of 42 can be interpreted as string since the method that is writing the values is exactly the same, just adressing different fields.